# Make payment with stripe from Card

Tags: php, stripe-payments, backend

I'm new to Stripe and payment integration in general.

I would like to implement a payment system in my application. I have already set the credit card input, which is also verified by creating a token of this type:

```
{
    "card": {
        "address_city": null,
        "address_country": null,
        "address_line1": null,
        "address_line1_check": null,
        "address_line2": null,
        "address_state": null,
        "address_zip": null,
        "address_zip_check": null,
        "brand": "Visa",
        "country": "US",
        "cvc_check": "unchecked",
        "dynamic_last4": null,
        "exp_month": 12,
        "exp_year": 2025,
        "funding": "credit",
        "id": "card_1HZFtCHAdtJCId9lZP626zJI",
        "last4": "4242",
        "name": null,
        "object": "card",
        "tokenization_method": null
    },
    "client_ip": "5.171.212.113",
    "created": 1601989654,
    "id": "tok_1HZFtCHAdtJCId9lxdU1jFVa",
    "livemode": false,
    "object": "token",
    "type": "card",
    "used": false
}
```

so far so good, what I should do is send this token to my php server (an external hosting without any particular library installed). Can anyone explain to me how to process the payment from back-end? I checked the documentation but none of them explain how to do it using a normal php hosting. I thank everyone in advance for taking the time!

Answer (score 1):

### Data Source: https://stripe.com/docs/api/

Considering you have already installed stripe you would follow these steps.
If not you should use composer to install it.

```
composer require stripe/stripe-php
```

### 1)Authentication

The Stripe API uses API keys to authenticate requests so you must auth first using your API keys to use anything. https://dashboard.stripe.com/login?redirect=/account/apikeys

```
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(INSERT_API_KEY_HERE);
```

### 2)Create a charge

You already got your card so you can charge it.

Edit: You can get all the data you need by making a request using the api. By the time you create a user in your app, you should also create a Customer using stripe and save their stripe-id in your database so you can access to their data.

### Creating a customer

```
$customer = $stripe->customers->create(['description' => 'My First Test Customer',]);
// Save your customer ID using $customer->id
```

### Charging the card

```
$stripe->charges->create([
  'amount' => 2000,
  'currency' => 'usd',
  'source' => 'INSERT_CARD_ID',
  'description' => 'My First Test Charge',
]);
```

---

Source:

A payment source to be charged. This can be the ID of a card (i.e., credit or debit card), a bank account, a source, a token, or a connected account. For certain sources—namely, cards, bank accounts, and attached sources—you must also pass the ID of the associated customer.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer Juan. While this is still supported, I would recommend looking at migrating to Payment Intents to get support for SCA: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/migration

Answer (score 0):

While @Juan has answered above using the Charges API, for an integration which supports [Strong Customer Authentication](https://stripe.com/docs/strong-customer-authentication) I would recommend using the Payment Intents API.

You can read through the [end-to-end guide for creating a payment](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?integration=elements) which includes both client and server code snippets in a variety of languages (including PHP). This is the recommend pattern.

Since you already have a `card_123` if you want to attempt payment without SCA support, you can actually go right to [creating the payment](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-card-without-authentication#web-charge-card):

```
\Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
  'amount' => 1234,
  'currency' => 'usd',
  // 'customer' => 'cus_567', // only if you've attached the card
  'payment_method' => 'card_123',
  'error_on_requires_action' => true,
  'confirm' => true,
]);
```